# What permissions should I request to subscribe to my own Facebook Page using Webhooks?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-permissions, facebook-webhooks

Since April '18, in order to use Webhooks to subscribe to the feed of my Facebook Page, I know that I have to send a request to Facebook showing the purpose of my application and the way I'll use this information. What I'm not sure about is what specific permissions should I add in that request. I know that I'll need "publish_pages" and "manage_pages" permission, but what about "Page Public Content Access"? Is it also necessary if I'm the admin of that Page?
Thanks!

Comment: No, you won’t need Page Public Content Access - that is for access to stuff on other public pages, that you don’t have admin access to. To perform actions on pages you own/have admin access to, manage_pages and publish_pages will do.

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much CBroe! I thought it was necessary because when I tried to obtainthe details from a particular post in my Page through its id it showed me an error message that suggested asking for that permission.

Comment: That sounds like you did not use a page access token ...?